# Get value of Xamarin Forms Custom Rendered Checkbox

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Checkbox view rendering properly in Xamarin Forms:

```
public class CheckBoxRenderer : ViewRenderer<LegalCheckbox, CheckBox>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<LegalCheckbox> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        CheckBox control = new Android.Widget.CheckBox(this.Context);
        control.Checked = false;
        control.Text = "I agree to terms";
        control.SetTextColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb (60, 60, 60));
        this.SetNativeControl(control);
    }
}
```

I want to check whether or not this checkbox is checked or not. Is there a way I can do this? Do I need to use dependency service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont think Dependency Services is going to help here its just an IOC container. Faced with the same issue I'd likely just set up some eventing

```
public class CheckBoxRenderer : ViewRenderer<LegalCheckbox, CheckBox>
{
    private LegalCheckbox legalCheckBox;
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<LegalCheckbox> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        legalCheckBox = e.NewElement;
        CheckBox control = new Android.Widget.CheckBox(this.Context);
        control.Checked = false;
        control.Text = "I agree to terms";
        control.SetTextColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb (60, 60, 60));
        base.SetNativeControl(control);
        Control.Click+=(sender,evt)=> 
            legalCheckBox.Checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    }
}
```

likewise adding a prop to my View

```
public class LegalCheckbox : View
{
    public bool Checked { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }
    public LegalCheckbox ()
    {
    }
}
```

Why?
I tend to think of the relationship between the Platform controls and the Xamarin Controls as a Model-View-Adapter pattern. The Platform Controls are your View. Your Xamarin Controls are your Model and your renderer does the Adaptations between.
To accomplish this we need somewhere in LegalCheckbox(Model) to store the Data we want to collect. Then we have to wire it up so that changes to the View cause changes to the model. Thus we add in the EventHandler for the OnClick event in the View to update our model.

It might appear at initial glace that all of this happens during the OnelementChanged Event. However its only actually wired up during at that point the actual Checked Event wont fire till long after OnElementChanged has completed and its resources been destroyed. Thus we need a reference to our LegalCheckbox out side of the OnElementChanged Event Handler that will still be there when the Clicked event fires.

Comment: The code is throwing `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` inside the Click event. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops sorry about that. Guess thats what I get for not testing the code :D You need to define CheckBox control as a class level field and then assign it within the body of OnElementChanged. The problem is the reference to "control" is destroyed when OnElementChanged Completes. Then later the "delegate" you assigned to Control.Clock attempts to use it and cant find it. I updated the GitHub example. See: https://github.com/DavidStrickland0/Xamarin-Forms-Samples/blob/master/RendererDemo/Droid/LegalCheckboxRenderer.cs

Comment: That edit fixed it. :) Thank you so much. How did you know that there needed to be a class level field and that it needed to be assigned inside OnElementChanged and that the CustomRenderer needs to have a property of the type of the class it is rendering in order to access its properties?

Comment: Updated the Answer with a bit of information about why.