# Event inside a custom renderer not firing

Tags: android, ios, forms, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm making a xamarin.form app,
I have a custom render for streaming the camera inside a view , I've followed the tutorial here:

[camera stream tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/CustomRenderers/ContentPage/)

I've managed to correctly show the camera stream inside a view, now I'm trying to create a button that toggle the flash:

here is my custom renderer:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Hangover.Camera.Factory;
using Hangover.GUIPersonalizzata;
using Xamarin.Forms;

//Questa classe permette di visualizzare lo stream della fotocamera
namespace Hangover.Camera.Views
{
    public class CameraStream:View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CameraProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Camera",
        returnType: typeof(CameraOptions),
        declaringType: typeof(CameraStream),
        defaultValue: CameraOptions.Rear);

        //Funzioni Fotocamera
        private Fotocamera _fotocamera;
        public event EventHandler flash_event;

        //costruttore di convenienza
        public CameraStream()
        {
        }

        public CameraStream(Fotocamera fotocamera){
            _fotocamera = fotocamera;
        }

        public CameraOptions Camera
        {
            get { return (CameraOptions)GetValue(CameraProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CameraProperty, value); }

        }

        public void gestisciFlash(BottoneSwitch btn){
            if (flash_event != null)
                flash_event.Invoke(btn, null);
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the iOS implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Hangover.Camera.Factory;
using Hangover.Camera.Views;
using Hangover.GUIPersonalizzata;
using Hangover.iOS.CustomRenderer;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraStream), typeof(CameraStreamRenderer))]
namespace Hangover.iOS.CustomRenderer
{
    public class CameraStreamRenderer : ViewRenderer<CameraStream, UICameraPreview>,ICameraFunctions 
    {
        UICameraPreview uiCameraPreview; // fotocamera nativa

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraStream> elem)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(elem);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                uiCameraPreview = new UICameraPreview(elem.NewElement.Camera);
                SetNativeControl(uiCameraPreview);

                var camera_stream = (CameraStream)elem.NewElement;
                camera_stream.flash_event += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                    Debug.Write("teeeest");
                };

            }
        }

        //Invocato quando la view viene chiusa
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Control.CaptureSession.Dispose();
                Control.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


        public void attivaFlash()
        {
            Debug.Write("flash");
            Debug.Write("flash");
            Debug.Write("flash");
        }

        public void distattivaFlash()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void scattaFoto()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ruotaFotocamera(BottoneSwitch btn)
        {
            if (!btn.isON){// mostro la post
                Debug.Write("mostra fotocamera post");
            }else{//mostra ant
                Debug.Write("mostra fotocamera ant");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so using this event:

```
public void gestisciFlash(BottoneSwitch btn){
            if (flash_event != null)
                flash_event.Invoke(btn, null);
        }
```

I should be able to print "teeest" but flash_event is always null and I don't know what to do.

I've tried the solution presented here [firing custom render event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221234/get-value-of-xamarin-forms-custom-rendered-checkbox/33221900#comment54334069_33221900) but with no luck.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraStream> e)
        {

            if(e.OldElement != null){

            }

            if(e.NewElement != null){

                if (Control == null)
                {
                    uiCameraPreview = new UICameraPreview(new Camera.CameraOptions());
                    SetNativeControl(uiCameraPreview);
                }

                var camera_stream = (CameraStream)e.NewElement;
                camera_stream.flash_event += (object sender, EventArgs ea) => {
                    attivaFlash();
                };
            }

            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
```

refactored the code as suggested by @Benl still not working , this:

```
 public void gestisciFlash(BottoneSwitch btn){
                if (flash_event != null)
                    flash_event.Invoke(btn, null);
            }
```

Is still null.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Assumption: Some camera device generating the flash/torch light event is attached.

CameraStreamRenderer.cs:

```
OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraStream> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control == null)
    {
        // Instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with
        // the SetNativeControl method
        uiCameraPreview = new UICameraPreview(e.NewElement.Camera);
        SetNativeControl(uiCameraPreview);
    }

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
        uiCameraPreview.Flash -= OnFlash;
    }
    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
        uiCameraPreview.Flash += OnFlash;
    }
}

void OnFlash(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Flash");
}
```

However, the `flash` event must be generated somewhere, not shown in the original question.

Assuming the `flash` event might be generated in `UICameraPreview` in an `Observer` with assumed key `"torchActive"`.

UICameraPreview.cs:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Flash;

protected virtual void OnFlash()
{
    Flash?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}

void Initialize()
{
    ...
    AVCaptureDevice device = ...
    ...
    if (device == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    device.AddObserver(
            key: "torchActive", 
            options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, 
            observer: (c) => 
                { 
                    OnFlash(); 
                });
```

`device.RemoveObserver` not shown above.

Comment: thank you for your input, but the event is still null. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?